# emacs 26: Symbol’s function definition is void: string-to-int

Tags: emacs

emacs-26.1-x86_64 org-mode

When I push with `org-mobile-push` I have this error:

```
Symbol’s function definition is void: string-to-int
```

I have no problem with a pull.

Comment: What do you mean by "make a push"?

Comment: I mean 'org-mobile-push to share on dropbox

Comment: "Push" and "pull" could have meant any number of things -- try to be very specific when you write a question.

Answer (score 8):

`string-to-int` has been an obsolete function since Emacs 22.1, and it was removed in 26.1.

The offending code needs to use `string-to-number` instead.

Use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `toggle-debug-on-error` to generate a stack trace when the error occurs, and find out what is trying to call that function.

(Alternatively, grep your config for `string-to-int`.)

Note that `string-to-int` was just an alias for `string-to-number` so you can safely rename any calls you find.  If the code is in some third-party library, you could try updating it to a newer version.  Failing that, raise a bug report with the author.

If you're completely lost for how to proceed, you could add this code somewhere early in your init file to restore the alias, which will enable the outdated code to work again:

```
(define-obsolete-function-alias 'string-to-int 'string-to-number "22.1")
```